# Word for the texture of a weathered rock?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for either a word or phrase of when a rock has been weathered by sea water and has become very rough - to the point where its texture is so dangerous and pointy that it just cuts through flesh like butter. I want to use this description to ultimately describe a person. That they've become such that coming close to them you're so easily hurt.

Sample: *"Now there is something different whereby them attacking me they actually draw blood from themselves. I've become [word]."*

"Bristle" is not strong enough. "Caustic" connotes something acidic, which I don't want. Maybe something between "barbed" and "jagged" might work, but I was wondering if anyone had a better idea.

Comment: Sea glass and beach pebbles are smooth as eggshells. Sounds like you have a set idea of what you want. Keep looking.

Comment: @YosefBaskin a [picture](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/abstract-colorful-sharp-rock-stone-texture-background-vintage-effect-abstract-colorful-sharp-rock-stone-texture-background-vintage-109219423.jpg) might [help](https://previews.123rf.com/images/hui/hui1704/hui170400034/75938234-red-brown-sea-rock-texture.jpg)

Comment: "weathered" is commonly used to describe textures and surfaces. Is there a reason you don't want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few.  **Scabrous** may suit the case:

> rough to the touch: such as 
> a: having small raised dots, scales, or points a scabrous leaf 
> b: covered with raised, roughened, or unwholesome patches 
> scabrous paint 
> scabrous skin

This has the added benefit of also meaning

> dealing with suggestive, indecent, or scandalous theme

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scabrous)

Synonyms of *scabrous*, or more specifically of **craggy** may be preferable, including, *rough-hewn*, *scraggy* or *asperous*.

[Theasaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/craggy)

Answer (score 1):

There are several words which you might apply to sharp rocks.
jagged, ragged, serrated, saw-toothed, toothed, shredding.
Or you might consider a descriptive phrase such as "like shark's teeth", "knife like".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to describe someone hardened by life, you can use words like "rugged" (which, besides meaning tough and unrelenting, also means "having a broken, rocky, and uneven surface" and "harsh and threatening in manner or appearance"), "hard-bitten," or "cast-iron." All these words denote long-held toughness.

Comment: None of these carry the idea of being "dangerous and pointy" that the question was after.

Comment: True, but I believe the words I have suggested do connote a sense of being weathered by seawater (or life, figuratively). Plus, they are often used to describe people, for whom the questioner wants the word to describe.